# How to open external files selected from a file explorer app on Android 11?

Tags: android

Up until now I was able to open audio files selected from a file explorer app either by guessing their path or by accessing the input stream from the received URI

```
context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
```

However this isn't possible anymore when targeting SDK 30 (android 11) as this generates a security exception.

How can an app open a file from its URI now?

Comment: No. This is still possible and THE way. Show the value of the uri. Show code. Which file explorer?

Comment: content://media/external/audio/media/15297 If I set the app target code to API 29 it works fine. I set it to 30 I get the security exception

Comment: Please fullfill all remarks if you wanna have solved your problem.

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [mcve] with the complete stack trace and the complete code that triggers the stack trace.